# Text Mining Library for Python

Tags: api, python-2.7, web2py, text-mining

I have to built a text mining application in web2py using python 2.x. The purpose of app is to collect data from websites save them in a text file then pass that text file to the program for text to matrix conversion and then finally I have to apply clustering on that data.

My question is what open source library or API can I use to cover text to matrix conversion and apply clustering on it for python 2.x?

Comment: do you know how much files you are going to work with ? and how lengthy they will be ? the answer might differ depending on the volume of the data ...

Answer (score 1):

I think [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) should fit your needs. It's difficult to say without knowing exactly what your data will look like, but there are many text manipulation functions and built-in clustering algorithms within scikit-learn's API.